# In-App Purchase Display Name and Description not properly loading - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am trying to enable In-App Purchases in Swift 4 for iOS and I can not get the Display Name and Description to properly show up (or load) in the app when I test. I do get the error handing message that I put in `if (products.count == 0) {`. I can't get the Product Title and Product Description that I set up in AppStoreConnect to properly load when I test my app. Instead the code thinks that there are no products because it runs the code in the `if (products.count == 0) {` closure. I quadruple checked everything else (i.e. Bundle ID, Product ID, StoreKit's imported, the delegates are set up, everything on the AppStoreConnect side is set up, etc.). There are no Xcode Warnings and the In-App Purchase status is "Ready To Submit". Any suggestions?

```
var product: SKProduct?
var productID = "myProductID"

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    var products = response.products
    if (products.count == 0) {  
        productTitle.text = "Warning"    // GETS DISPLAYED
        productDescripton.text = "Unable to connect to In-App Purchase."    // GETS DISPLAYED
    } else {
        product = products[0]
        productTitle.text = product?.localizedTitle
        productDescripton.text = product?.localizedDescription
        buyButton.isEnabled = true
        buyButton.alpha = 1.0
    }
    let invalid = response.invalidProductIdentifiers
    for product in invalid {
        print("\(product)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any values in the `invalidProductIdentifiers` array?  Are you testing on a real device, not the simulator?

Comment: It's printing the Product ID that I set up in AppStoreConnect. I'm testing in simulator.

Comment: You can't test in app purchase on the simulator.  You must use a real device.

Comment: Unfortunately, I got same result on real device.

Comment: Paulw11, I overlooked three things and that was one of them, so I gave you an upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a rookie at integrating In-App Purchases, then you should read this. If you have clean code and you think that you set everything up properly in App Store Connect, but still can't test properly. Specifically, if your products array is showing empty when it shouldn't be. Then, make sure that you have done the following:

1) Set up a Sandbox Tester via Users and Access in App Store Connect. This needs to be set up with an email that is not already used with iTunes, App Store, or Apple.

2) Filled out all of the necessary forms in Agreements, Tax, and Banking via App Store Connect. You'll know that everything is filled out when Paid Applications shows an Active Status.

3) Are testing on a real device that has been signed out of iTunes and App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Common things that will cause this without warning are:

1. Your products aren't in the 'Ready to Submit' stage. This is most often from a missing screenshot, which is required even for Sandbox (you can upload a blank image for sandbox testing).
2. You haven't signed the 'Paid Applications' agreement in App Store Connect

Here's a good blog post that covers everything in a little more detail: [Configuring In-app Products is Hard](https://www.revenuecat.com/2018/10/11/configuring-in-app-products-is-hard)

Comment: Do you have to sign the Paid Applications Agreement and set up a bank account even if you are just testing?

Comment: You do, but don't ask me why :)

Comment: enc_life, Signing the Paid Applications agreement was one of the things that I overlooked, so I gave you an upvote. Thanks.